# How to use GROUP BY for a column with an alias?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables
`tblVendor`, `tblVendorItem` and `tblEventItem`.

`tblEventItem` has the columns `Quantity` and `Price`.

I want to show a Vendor's **`VendorItem`** on a *chart* based on their **Sales.**, where Sales will be a calculated as `column (Quantity * Price)`.

I have tried the following query but it´s not working correctly. It says: `Invalid column name: Sales`.

```
SELECT        tblEventItem.Quantity * tblEventItem.Price AS 'Sales', tblEventItem.VendorItemID, tblVendorItem.Name AS 'VendorItemName'
FROM            tblEventService INNER JOIN
                         tblEventItem ON tblEventService.EventServiceID = tblEventItem.EventServiceID INNER JOIN
                         tblVendorItem ON tblVendorItem.VendorItemID = tblEventItem.VendorItemID INNER JOIN
                         tblVendor ON tblVendorItem.VendorID = tblVendor.VendorID
WHERE        (tblEventService.ServiceID = 3)
GROUP BY 'Sales'
```

Comment: @DinavAhire : You cannot use group by with the sales column, you have to group by either VendorItemID or else the VendorID

Comment: why do you need grouping there? VendroItem, VendorItem name, you can calculate Quantity * Price. Do you need sum of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CROSS APPLY or OUTER APPLY for that. This does not affect performance, however it makes code more readable and easier to use.

```
-- MS SQL
CREATE TABLE #test
(
    b INT, 
    c INT
);

INSERT INTO #test VALUES (1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,3)

SELECT s.Sales, COUNT(*)  FROM #test a CROSS APPLY  (SELECT b*c AS 'Sales') s
GROUP BY s.Sales;
```

In your case it will be something like:

```
SELECT
    s.Sales ,
    tblEventItem.VendorItemID ,
    tblVendorItem.Name AS 'VendorItemName'
FROM
    tblEventService
    INNER JOIN tblEventItem ON tblEventService.EventServiceID = tblEventItem.EventServiceID
    INNER JOIN tblVendorItem ON tblVendorItem.VendorItemID = tblEventItem.VendorItemID
    INNER JOIN tblVendor ON tblVendorItem.VendorID = tblVendor.VendorID
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT tblEventItem.Quantity * tblEventItem.Price Sales)  s
WHERE
    ( tblEventService.ServiceID = 3 )
ORDER BY
    'Sales' DESC;
```

It is very unclear what is need to be grouped by, but hope that with this query you can do your plans.

Comment: it says invalid column name Sales

Comment: Fix your query in the question and then I'll be able to give you proper answer

Comment: the query is fine sir. if i use order by, then the reult is showing perfectly. but in group by it says invalid column name Sales.

Comment: It is not fine. 1) you have missing ')'. Another thing is that subquery is named as 'sub', but in select you are selecting tblEventItem columns

Comment: SELECT        tblEventItem.Quantity * tblEventItem.Price AS 'Sales', tblEventItem.VendorItemID, tblVendorItem.Name AS 'VendorItemName'
FROM            tblEventService INNER JOIN
                         tblEventItem ON tblEventService.EventServiceID = tblEventItem.EventServiceID INNER JOIN
                         tblVendorItem ON tblVendorItem.VendorItemID = tblEventItem.VendorItemID INNER JOIN
                         tblVendor ON tblVendorItem.VendorID = tblVendor.VendorID
WHERE        (tblEventService.ServiceID = 3)
ORDER BY 'Sales' DESC

Comment: why do you need grouping there? VendroItem, VendorItem name, you can calculate Quantity * Price. Do you need sum of that?

Comment: i want to show a chart. there will be vendorItems and their sale(Quantity*Price in my case) show i need to group `Sales`. so that i will be able to show the chart of vendorItems based on their sales.

Comment: what do you mean by grouping there? Do you want sum of all sales per vendor?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74909/discussion-between-dinav-ahire-and-sidux).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT        tblVendorItem.Name, tblEventItem.Quantity * tblEventItem.Price AS 'Sale'
FROM            tblEventService INNER JOIN
                         tblEventItem ON tblEventService.EventServiceID = tblEventItem.EventServiceID INNER JOIN
                         tblVendorItem ON tblEventItem.VendorItemID = tblVendorItem.VendorItemID INNER JOIN
                         tblVendor ON tblVendorItem.VendorID = tblVendor.VendorID
WHERE        (tblEventService.VendorID =@VendorID)
             GROUP BY  tblVendorItem.Name,tblEventItem.Quantity, tblEventItem.Price
```